# How Would I Move This Animation To The Player's Position?

Tags: python, pygame

I made this animation using a tutorial, and set it up to where if you're facing right to activate the animation, but all of my attempts at moving the animation to the player's location have failed. The animation needs to be activated using the space key, and take place inside the `onpress[pygame.K_Space]:` function. Where the code takes place isn't much of a concern for me.

```
# --- Imports ---
import pygame, os, random
# --- Screen Dimensions ---
SCR_WIDTH = 1020
SCR_HEIGHT = 510
# --- Colors ---
WHITE = [240, 240, 240]
# --- Game Constants ---
FPS = 60
# --- Fonts ---
pygame.font.init()
TNR_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Times_New_Roman', 27)
TNR_LARGE_FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('Times_New_Roman', 65)
# --- Dictionaries ---
images = {}
# --- Classes ---
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySprite, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka1.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka2.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka3.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka4.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka5.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka6.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka7.png'))
        self.images.append(pygame.image.load('Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/rka8.png'))
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(5, 5, 150, 198)
    def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= len(self.images):
            self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
# --- Functions
def clip(value, lower, upper):
    return min(upper, max(value, lower))
def load_images():
    path = 'Desktop/Files/Dungeon Minigame/'
    filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.png')]
    for name in filenames:
        imagename = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
        images[imagename] = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(path, name))
def game():
    my_sprite = MySprite()
    my_group = pygame.sprite.Group(my_sprite)
    score = 0
    lives = 3
    playerX = 80
    playerY = 100
    direction = 'left'
            def move(self, speed = 1):
                if self.x > playerX:
                    self.x -= speed
                elif self.x < playerX:
                    self.x += speed

                if self.y < playerY:
                    self.y += speed
                elif self.y > playerY:
                    self.y -= speed

            def draw(self):
                screen.blit(images['r_zombie'], (self.x, self.y))
    while True:
        screen.blit(images['background'], (0, 0))
        score_text = TNR_FONT.render('Score: ' + str(score), True, WHITE)
        lives_text = TNR_FONT.render('Lives: ', True, WHITE)
        screen.blit(score_text, (20, 20))
        screen.blit(lives_text, (840, 20))
        heart_images = ["triple_empty_heart", "single_heart", "double_heart", "triple_heart"]
        lives = clip(lives, 0, 3)
        screen.blit(images[heart_images[lives]], (920, 0))
        onpress = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        dx = 0
        if onpress[pygame.K_a]:
            dx -= 3
            direction = 'left'
        if onpress[pygame.K_d]:
            dx += 3
            direction = 'right'
        playerX += dx

        dy = 0
        if onpress[pygame.K_w]:
            dy -= 3
        if onpress[pygame.K_s]:
            dy += 3
        playerY += dy

        if onpress[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if direction == 'right':
                my_group.update()
                my_group.draw(screen)

        if dx > 0:
            screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))
        elif dx < 0:
            screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))
        if direction == 'left':
            screen.blit(images['l_knight'], (playerX, playerY))
        else:
            screen.blit(images['r_knight'], (playerX, playerY))

        playerX = clip(playerX, 8, 949)
        playerY = clip(playerY, 5, 440)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
# --- Main ---
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Minigame')
load_images()
game()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position of the `rect` attribute of the `MySprite` object.

```py
my_sprite.rect.topleft = (playerX, playerY)
```

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` mehtod of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]